# Unable to make "https" request from WP8 phonegap app

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, cordova, windows-phone-8, https

I am unable to make "https" request on phonegap  WP8 app. However, it works with "http". I am unsure if its the IE problem or any security exception. I am using lumia 520 for testing the app. Tried running the same code on the device browser(lumia 520) and got same results. Also tried adding $.support.cors = true and jQuery.support.cors = true;  Also tried editing config.xml changing " access origin="*" " to specify my server url. Same code works in other browsers and Android, ios phonegap apps. here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width = device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>myPage</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function auth(){

    var serverURL = "https://XXXXXX.YYYYY.com/file1/servlet"; 
    try {
        var value = $('#name1').val();
        var value1 = $('#pass1').val();
        var key = $('#key').val();
        var model="Browser";
          var make="Browser";
          var version='2.40';
        var formData = {
            "UserID" : value,
            "Password" : value1,
            "Type" : "Login",
            "MAKE" : make,
            "MODEL" : model,
            "APP_VERSION" : version,
            "Hybrid" : "Hybrid"
        }
    } catch (Err) {

    }
    console.log(formData)
    var JSONs = JSON.stringify(formData);

    $.ajax({
        crossDomain : true,
        type : "POST",
        url : serverURL,
        data : JSONs,
        datatype : "json",
        success : onSuccessLogin,
        error : errorFailed
    });
     function onSuccessLogin(data) {
         console.log("success"+JSON.stringify(data));
         alert(JSON.stringify(data));
         var returnData = JSON.parse(data);
         if(returnData.ErrorMsg == "") {
             alert("Login Success");
         }
     }
     function errorFailed(error) {
            alert("Unable to process"+JSON.stringify(error));
        }
}
</script>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="Login">
        <input type="hidden" id="key" value="0000000000000000000" /> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="name1" value="" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass1" value="" />
        <a href="#" onclick="auth();">Login</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with "https" request it always returns {“readyState”:0,“responseText”:“”,“status”:0,“statusText”:“error”}. Kindly help

Answer (score 2):

It isn't an "HTTPS" problem, you can try with this example

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=2&per_page=100', false);
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
  $(document.body).append(" -> "+req.responseText + "," + req.readyState + "<br>" + window.location);
}
req.send(null);
```

The problem is from the server, you should add the header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

or your WP URI

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ms-appx-web://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

you can get your app "ms-appx-web://xxxx..." value with a "window.location" call or look at your .appxmanifest in Identity Name="xxxxx...." ...>

hope this help!

Comment: Thanks alot for the suggetions. I had tried all that :), It did work in other cases

Answer (score 1):

It was to do with Device date... My mistake, never checked the device date, it was not synced and was 1 year ahead of the current time. Resetting it did the magic!!!

Comment: you saved me the day!